# If I don't enable iCloud backup, will I have to exlude my document directory to prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, nsdocumentdirectory, icloud-drive

After reading this question, you would surely be thinking to mark this as duplicate. I am aware of following solution to exclude file or folder. But, do I really need to do it if my App does not support `iCloud documents` under `Capabilities` in Xcode ?

Here is the solution which is applicable for my case:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(filePath:String) -> Bool
{
    let URL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

    assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath), "File \(filePath) does not exist")

    var success: Bool

    do {
        try URL.setResourceValue(true, forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
        success = true

    } catch let error as NSError {

        success = false
        print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)");
    }

    return success
}
```

Is it necessary if I disable `iCloud documents` under `Capabilities` in Xcode as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are for two different purpose.

**iCloud in Xcode Capability:** It's for enabling iCloud related features in your application.

**NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey:** By default the user data is backed up to iCloud by iOS (If user opted iCloud backup). Only user data not application data.

*User Data:* The content user created using your app falls under this category

*App Data:* The images/videos/any other file that you download or store in the document directory for your app's functionality

Comment: Thanks..upvoted. Can you give me an example of User data ?

Comment: @NSPratik: User Data like, if your app is a text editor, user may be creating a document using it. It falls under that user data category. Or user is downloading/saving any content using your app falls under that category. Anything that is created by user falls under user category, anything that is created by the app without user knowledge and intervention falls under app data.

Comment: So If I just download few images/PDFs and saving those in NSDocumentDirectory for user to see, do I need to exclude it for iTunes/iCloud backup ? Note: user is not editing and saving those. Files downloaded are just readonly.

Comment: @NSPratik: yes, it should be. Your app is downloading it right and it can be downloaded again.

Comment: But as per you, my downloaded files come under `App Data`

Comment: Yes, and app data shouldn't be backed up, so that flag must be set. I mean excluded from back-up

Comment: @NSPratik: The files you download for your app's working should be stored in the cache directory, it's the best place to avoid such issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161359/discussion-between-nspratik-and-midhun-mp).